# Error with xstdde "could not deduce template argument..."

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sfml

I'm working on a asteroids game replica. This error I'm getting is beyond my understanding so I hope you can help.

In my code I have a class name `asteroid` that stores every asteroid object. Within this class I have a public function that's called `create()` which has the parameter `sf::ConvexShape` (if you don't know what `sf::ConvexShape` is, it is a function in the SFML library). I also have a `std::map<asteroid, sf::ConvexShape>` to store asteroid objects as the key and their shapes as the `.second`

The error is a runtime error, everything is fine in the compiler. The error reports are gibberish to me, but there was a part that mentioned "iterator" and "std::vector" which makes me think I'm doing something wrong passing iterators to the `create()` function?

**Here is the error log:**

`Error  5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const asteroid'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  10  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const asteroid'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  12  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const asteroid'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  9   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const asteroid' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const asteroid'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const asteroid' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const asteroid'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  11  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const asteroid'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const asteroid'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

`Error  13  error C2676: binary '<' : 'const asteroid' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef  180 1   SFML testing`

Also full sauce [here](http://pastebin.com/XXV74gE8).

Why am I getting these errors? How can I fix it?

Let me know if there is something I forgot to mention, its hard to know what to ask when I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry but your code needs to be included in your post, not stored on an external site and linked .

Comment: That is *not* a runtime error.  It is coming out of the compiler.

Comment: Sorry Captain, I didn't know. Should I fix it or is it too late?

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` stores things in a sorted order.  If you don't tell it how to sort, it will use `operator <`.  Your problem is that given:

```
 asteroid a, b;
 a < b; // Not defined.
```

You need something like:

```
 bool operator <( const asteroid& lhs, const asteroid& rhs)
 {
     ????
 }
```

Except that you can't use the position (because that keeps changing).  Perhaps you should do:

```
 class asteroid
 {
     static unsigned global_id;
     unsigned id;
     .... // Previous contents as before.
 }

 asteroid::asteroid() : id (global_id++) { ... }
```

and then

```
 bool operator <( const asteroid& lhs, const asteroid& rhs)
 {
     lhs.id < rhs.id;
 }
```

Comment: Where would I place the code exactly? Inside xstdde? main?

Comment: You need to declare the `operator <` in your header file, and then define it (actually implement it) in a .cpp (as appropriate)  Similarly for the constructor (and the class static)